# Previously Terminal prompt showed the whole path now just current directory, why has my Terminal prompt changed?

Tags: terminal, bash, path

I've noticed a few strange changes to my mac.  One of which is that now my Terminal prompt only shows the current directory and not the full path (or the path from the current user).  Do you know why this might have changed and how to change it back to show the full path?

eg it used to show something like

```
username/Music/GarageBand$
```

but now it shows

```
mycomputername:GarageBand username$
```

Comment: What did you change/upgrade since "before"?

Comment: @nohillside it seems this setting was in my .bash_profile file.  Unfortunately my .bash_profile file has been inexplicably deleted or was moved yesterday (not by me nor do I have any explanation).  Do you know why my bash_profile might have been removed?  Could it have been moved somewhere?  I didn't make a change to it, the file no longer exists in the root of my user folder (bash_history exists).  Unfortunately there had been a problem with timemachine for a few months and i've just realised my other backup utility wasn't backing up that directory (I'd created a number of custom scripts)

Comment: I can't see onto your machine nor do I know what you did yesterday :-) Any software installation/upgrade, any Terminal command you ran maybe?

Comment: Ha! fair enough! I'm guessing that something has deleted it.  Thank you anyway (I've just found a backup though)

Answer (score 1):

The following script needs to be in .bash_profile

```
PS1='\w $ '
```

(an unrelated problem had meant my bash_profile file was removed)